# Radio buttons on reputation graph in network profile are broken

Tags: bug, network-profile, reputation-graph

The radio buttons which can be used to toggle between 'top 5 accounts' and 'all accounts' in the [network reputation graph](https://stackexchange.com/users/current?tab=reputation) are broken; selecting the other option works (the graph is updated) but the radio button itself is not set:

[image]

Comment: Who even knew this thing existed!